# How can I setup cron job in Wamp Windows?

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab, magento-cron

How can I configure the Magento 2 cron job in Wamp Windows? For upgrade Magento 2 asking cron in Wamp localhost.

Comment: please check my answer. Hope that'll help you.

Comment: @MagenX I am using wamp

Comment: i am using wamp. read my post carefully. FYI Moderator

Comment: please use search, wamp and windows are the same stack...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento 2, there are three cron jobs required. Because windows doesn’t have cron, we have to use a bat file and configure it to run as a scheduled task as shown below:

> 1. Find the location of `php.exe` – In you have Wamp installed, it’s in `Drive:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25` e.g `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25`
> 2. Go to a folder and create a file named yourcron.bat
> 3. Edit this file and paste 3 lines shown below:
>
>    in the following file I have added to cron job for re-indexing and
>      cache
>
>    ```
>    C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe C:\wamp\www\magento2\bin\magento cron:run
>    C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe C:\wamp\www\magento2\update\cron.php
>    C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe C:\wamp\www\magento2\bin\magento setup:cron:run
>    C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe C:\wamp\www\magento2\bin/magento indexer:reindex
>    C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.exe C:\wamp\www\magento2\bin/magento cache:flush
>    ```
> 4. Save the file, open command prompt and enter following command:
>
>    ```
>    schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 5 /tn Magento\Cron /tr C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\yourcron.bat
>    ```
> 5. Now click on `Start –> Control Panel –> Administrative Tools –> Task Scheduler`
> 6. Expand **Task Schedule Library** from the left hand column and click Magento.
> 7. Select **Cron** from the middle panel, click **properties** from the right pane under selected items.
> 8. Under **Security Options**, click the **Change User or Group** button.
> 9. Now in the current window, enter **System username in the object name box and click check names**. Click OK to close the User window, and OK
>      to close the Cron properties Window, and close Task Scheduler.
> 10. Cron job setup is successful and it will run every 5 minutes.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @zus check 4th step and replace 1 instead of 5 and your work done.

Comment: Above one create command right, how can i edit the min.

Comment: schtasks /create /sc minute /mo 1 /tn Magento\Cron /tr C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\yourcron.bat

Comment: May i know why am getting this error while running cron,  https://snag.gy/VAPJyG.jpg

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a cron.php file (the code you want to execute at a regular interval)
2. Create a CRON.BAT file, copy and past the below code in the file
   D:\xampp\php\php.exe D:\xampp\htdocs\Application\cron.php

The path I have written is according to my xampp and cron.php file, update the path of files according to your system directory

3. To schedule a task
   Click on start > All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Scheduled Tasks

Or you can go directly to Control Panel > Scheduled Tasks

Right click in the folder
New > Schedule Task

Give appropriate name to the Task.
In the RUN text field… Type the complete path of the CRON.BAT file
in my case it is
D:\xampp\htdocs\Application\CRON.BAT

Set the schedule of the job, you can use advanced button if required.

I hope this helps.